# How to redirect to clean URL (remove query string from URL) with RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-302

How to redirect to `www.example.com` when accessing `www.example.com?mobile=0` after the cookie is set?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

What this code does is to redirect `www.example.com` to `m.example.com` if accessed from a mobile device, but not when accessing `www.example.com?mobile=0` which will set a cookie to keep the user on the main site even on a mobile device.

**I would like to add a 302 redirect from `www.example.com?mobile=0` to the clean URL `www.example.com` once the cookie preventing the redirection is set.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Append this rule at the end of your existing rules:**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?mobile=0[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=302,L]
```